# How to increase the amount of memory memcached uses in MAMP on MAC 10.8

Tags: php, memcached

How do I increase the maximum memory size of memcache in MAMP running on MAC 10.8? The default is set to 1MB

Answer (score 0):

In memcached.conf there is a line that reads

```
# Start with a cap of 64 megs of memory. It's reasonable, and the daemon default
# Note that the daemon will grow to this size, but does not start out holding this much
# memory
-m 64
```

So all you need to do is change `-m 64` to whatever value you want.

Comment: where is the memcached.conf file located in mac 10.8

Comment: I am using MAMP to manage both PHP, MYSQL and MEMCACHED server. How do I adjust the memory size using MAMP

Comment: MAMP just stands for Mac, Apache, MySQL and PHP. So all you're saying is you're running your server on a Mac. I assume memcache will have a similar setup and configuration as it does under linux. So in a terminal type find / -name "memcached.conf"

Comment: The memcached.conf file cannot be found in my mac. Here is a result of the executing the find command in terminal                            sudo find / -name "memcached.conf"
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory